# In NetLogo, is 'with' a form of asking?

Tags: netlogo

With the following code:

```
breed [girls girl] ;pink
breed [boys boy] ;green

to go
clear-all
create-girls 10 [move-to one-of patches]
create-boys 10 [move-to one-of patches]
end
```

I was expecting the next line to have girls show the count of boys of the same colour i.e. "show the count of boys with colour equals colour of me":

```
ask girls [show count boys with [color = [color] of self]]
```

But instead this counts every boy. This is the code that does the job:

```
ask girls [show count boys with [color = [color] of myself]]
```

Why does self (me) refer to the boys and myself (the turtle that asked me) refer to the girls? Is the keyword 'with' asking the boys to do something and that's what switches it over?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

The `ask` and `with` primitives both work with a "code block" (the part delimited by `[` and `]`) that operate in the context of a particular agent. Inside that block, `self` refers to the current agent (the one from the block's context) and myself to the "outer" agent (the one in the context of which `with` or `ask` was called).

The main difference between `ask` and `with` is that `ask` takes a *command* block (one that most likely *does* something) and `with` takes a *reporter* block (one that just returns a value).

Note that `with` is not the only primitive using reporter blocks: `of` is another common case. Using a variation on your previous example:

```
ask girls [
  show [color = [color] of myself] of boys
]
```

would have each girl show a list of boolean values (one value for each boy in the list, in random order): `true` if the boy was the same color as the girl, `false` otherwise.